# Using Regex With Jmeter Regular Expression Extractor not working

Tags: jmeter

I would like from this in the Response Body of my Request to get the request Number

```
[
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "$type": "Op.Request, Op",
    "RequestNumber": "2022.06145",
    "WorkTitle": "Title",
    "Status": null,
    "StatusCode": "NEW",
    "Substatus": null,
    "PriorityCode": "MED",
    "Priority": null,
    "WorkflowManager": null,
    "WorkflowManagerId": null,
    "RequestDescription": null,
    "CorporateBodyCode": "PUBL",
    "CorporateBody": null,
```

This is my setting

[image]

[json response body Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rzot.png)

[Debug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY3Kc.png)

Do I Forgot something?

Expecting to get the value of my variable and getting Empty value

Comment: Yeah, `Template` must be `$2$`

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to change "Field to check" to `Body`
2. [You shouldn't post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), for example personally I'm not willing to analyze your regex by looking at low resolution screenshot with shitty yellow highlighting.
3. [JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/4017) so using regular expressions for parsing it is not the best idea, have you considered using [JSON Extractor instead](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)?